# Looking for If/Then function

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, pivot-table, dynamic-pivot

I have a workbook comprised of forty-something Tabs of zip codes that each contain lists of Store Numbers. I need to state NEXT TO each store number either "Legacy" or "Swipe Up". There are thousands so it's too long to do manually with a drop-down selection. The source list of which the stores are "legacy" vs "swipe up" is under the first tab named "legacy vs swipe up" in my workbook.

How would I make this a function?
[image] I have added a screenshot of my workbook

I was thinking an If then function would work but I am not sure of the formula layout.

This is the layout of my "Legacy vs Swipe up" tab looks like
[image]

Comment: Probably a VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH depending on your data layout in the "legacy vs swipe up" workbook.

Comment: What about a pivot table? I need "Legacy" or "Swipe up" next to each store number listed under each tab which is based on the list from the first tab in my workbook.

Answer (score 1):

A formula using the **XLOOKUP** function will give you the result that you are looking for.

The function is structured like this.

```
=XLOOKUP(lookup_value, lookup_array, return_array, [if_not_found])
```

Your formula would look like this.

```
=XLOOKUP(B3,'legacy vs swipe up'!$B$2:$B$15,'legacy vs swipe up'!$A$2:$A$15,"MISSING store number")
```

For your purposes, extend the **lookup_array** and **return_array** in the formula to include the used cell in the *legacy vs swipe up* worksheet.  Example: If your last cell was *6000*, then **$15** would become **$6000**.

[image]

[image]

Added some random data to the *legacy vs swipe up* worksheet so that there were store values to match the store values being looked up.